# Datagrid not updating when item added to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a Client entity that has a collection of Notes.

I have a DataGrid in my View that is databound to my Client.AuditableNotes collection and I can see the notes if they already exist in the database. However if I add a new AuditableNote into the collection it does not appear?

My ClientEditViewModel has the following for my Client property:

```
    //Backing Field
private Client _client;
.
.
.
//Property
public Client Client
{
    get { return _client; }
    set
    {
        _client = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Client");
    }
}
//Upon my NoteEdit usercontrol returning control back to clienteditviewmodel
public void NoteEditFinished(AuditableNote note)
{
    if (note != null)
    {
        note.AddedBy = _dbContext.SystemUsers.First();
        if (note.AuditableNoteId == 0)
        {
            if (this.Client.AuditableNotes != null)
            {
                this.Client.AuditableNotes.Add(note);
            }
            else
            {
                List<AuditableNote> notes = new List<AuditableNote>();
                notes.Add(note);
                this.Client.AuditableNotes = notes;
            }
        }
        else
        {
             AuditableNote existingNote = this.Client.AuditableNotes.Where(an => an.AuditableNoteId == note.AuditableNoteId).First();
            existingNote = note;
        }
    }
}
```

My Datagrid is defeined as so:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdNotes" MinWidth="180" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Client.AuditableNotes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Background="Transparent"
          RowBackground="Transparent"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          DataContext="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Header="Warning">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="25" Height="20"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Warning}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="MyImage" Value="/Assets/Images/symbol_error.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Warning}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="MyImage" Value="/Assets/Images/symbol_information.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding Note, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="290"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Added By" Binding="{Binding AddedBy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Added" Binding="{Binding DateAdded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding}"` is usually pointless, also `ItemsSource` does not bind back to the source, `TwoWay` does nothing. Also the `Client` class code would be important, further the bound collection surely is not guaranteed to be observable, you set it to a plain `List<T>`, what do you expect...

Comment: What do I expect??? Erm, the datagrid to reflect the addition of an item to the collection?